# Push notifications in Android 8 using IONIC v1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap-plugin-push

I have an app developed in IONIC v1 and I am using phonegap-plugin-push to receive notifications, my current plugin version is 1.3.1 and when I am checking on Android 8, 9 then I can see that notifications are not coming.

I have checked this plugin's repo and I have read that we need to upgrade this plugin to latest version so I have upgraded plugin from 1.3.1 to 2.1.3 version but my IONIC version is still v1. Ever since I have updated plugin I am getting this error "INVALID_SENDER"

Here are more details:

cordova --version                                    9.0.0

cordova platform version android                     7.1.0

So, main issue is that I have an app in IONIC v1 and I want that users of PIE & Oreo should also get notifications. I don't want to convert whole app to IONIC v2 or v3

Comment: please check your senderID from firebase is correct

Comment: @sunielkalwani yes, I have checked senderID from firebase and it is correct.. Actually i have downloaded googleservices.json file from firebase and included in the project.

Comment: @sunielkalwani Yes, your suggestion worked. I checked again and found that there was one more google-services.json file under platforms/android/app folder and that json file was pointing to wrong project number. So, I am not receiving that invalid sender id now but still app is crashing when I am sending notification

Comment: can you tell me the error logs

Comment: @sunilkalwani problem was fixed. there was an issue of google play services as I also had google plus plugin installed in the app. Thanks for your prompt help